# Do forum signature link count as backlink?

Tags: seo, links

I am new on SEO so there are many questions arises on my mind about SEO. I have seen there has a signature area where I can paste a link.

1. Does this link will count as a backlink?
2. If I post 500 message, 500 backlink will create for signatures?
3. If I have .me site, then can I put my site link to all kind of forum?
4. I have a photo editing service site. Can I put this site link to forum related with SEO?

Sorry if any typos mistake.

Comment: This really is too broad and opinion-based since it depends on the _type_ of link (research "nofollow" versus "dofollow" links) and the quality & relevance of the site you're posting them on...just spamming your link anywhere you can is not a good SEO strategy, and may even work against you.

Comment: I have a photo editing service related site. So should I only put that site's link only photography related forum's signature?

Comment: The Value to your profile will be directly proportional to your link juice value. Do one thing. Put a standard signature and add value to the forum here value means adding relevant answers which will increase the numbers of a post for you. 
Now, add your URL to the signature and then you can expect some good value from it. But, make sure if your answers are irrelevant to the question or the link you are posting then it makes no sense.